# Get the next 7 characters following every instance of a specific string in a file

Tags: perl

I am looking for a way to get the 7 characters following every instance of the word `"ISBN="` in a file. There is one `ISBN=` per line in the file.

So something like...

```
my @data = ();
my $word = "ISBN=";

foreach my $line (@file) {
    if (index($line, $word) ge 0) {
        my $d = next seven characters;
        push (@data, $d);
    }
}
```

I have no clue...

Comment: You should iterate over the file using `while (<$fh>)` instead of slurping it into an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($line =~ /\Q$word\E(.{7})/) {
  push(@data, $1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. @TLP, Barmar is right, $line should be used instead of $word. But I didn't use string names that were particularly enlightening...

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a regex and capture would be easier:

```
if ($line =~ /ISBN=(.{7})/) {
    push @data, $1;
}
```

Comment: I think the regex needs the *g* modifier.  Look at perlreftut at perldoc.perl.org.

Comment: @EricJablow Why do you think this?

Comment: @EricJablow No, I think we'll manage just fine without matching multiple times. Especially since the OP said each line had only one `ISBN=` string.

Comment: You're using `$word` where it should be `$line`. `$word` contains the prefix that we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To get a fixed number of characters from a known index in a string, use the [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function:

```
my $d = substr $line, index($line, $word) + length($word), 7;
```